# Powershell Turtle Functionality - Is there a way to mimic the Python Turtle in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, graphics, turtle-graphics

Powershell Turtle Functionality - Is there a way to mimic the Python Turtle in Powershell?

I have searched the internet and can only find people creating functions to place dashes, underscores or pipes to make horizontal or vertical "lines".

Comment: What's "the Python Turtle"? Some sort of customizable mascot?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It was invented by the [Logo language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)#Turtle_and_graphics) as a way to teach programming to kids. [Python module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: The Python Turtle is a way to move an object around on the screen, leaving a solid line behind it as it moves.  I took a course on Python a while back, and am now going back over the course using Powershell instead.  In this section of the course, the Turtle is an introduction to graphics leading up to rudimentary games.  I am having a difficult time finding something comparable in Powershell.  Any help on this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is something similar for PowerShell, however if you want to learn PowerShell you could try [PS Koans](https://github.com/vexx32/PSKoans)

Comment: Thanks Santiago.  There is a course on Udemy called "100 Days of Code: The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp for 2021" that I really liked but could not find anything similar to it for Powershell so decided to re-take that course but instead write everything in Powershell.  Currently about 1/4 of the way through it.  

Earlier today I was trying to look into Powershell  Graphics.DrawPath(Pen, GraphicsPath) Method & System.Drawing.Drawing2D Namespace, but it seemed like it utilized predetermined points to plot results.

Comment: I have been looking at some Snake games code and perhaps I could trim down one of those and make a Turtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no built in Turtle functionality in PowerShell.  The best approach seems to be customizing your own function by some unique method or using one of the aforementioned methods to build it for your self.  When I get to that point, and should it be something worth while, then it will be posted.  Thanks to all at Stack Overflow!